# Does caret (^) in semver matches pre-release when pre-release version is the latest available version?

Tags: npm, versioning, semantic-versioning

Consider having library (e. g. NPM package) with these versions:

- 1.0.0
- 1.0.2
- 1.1.0-prerelease

If I specify `^1.0.0` in my dependencies, what will be version that will be installed? `1.1.0-prerelease` is the latest version, but I don't think any pre-release version satisfies range where I don't specify pre-release part. I have tried using https://semver.npmjs.com, but lodash doesn't have a situation where pre-release was also latest.

Comment: You can enter any package name in the box; it just defaults to lodash...

Comment: True, but I would have to find appropriate library on NPM (or create one myself). I'll probably do that, if no-one can answer it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Typically* a range with a caret (`^`) prefix such as `^1.0.0` *does not* result in the prerelease version `1.1.0-prerelease` being installed.

So given the examples provided in your question the version that will *typically* be installed is `1.0.2`.

**Note:** However, that logic may not always be the case - I'll explain why shortly.

---

#### Example of *typical* logic using the Semver Calculator:

At time of writing this, a better example to illustrate the *typical* logic using the Semver Calculator is to test using [`typescript`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript) instead of `lodash`.

Using the [semver calculator](https://semver.npmjs.com/):

1. Pick `typescript` as the package
2. Enter a range of `^4.0.0`

As you can see it selects `4.0.2` and does not select `4.2.0-dev.20201204` (which was published to the npm registry after `4.0.2`). This logic is *typically* what will happen.

#### When may the *typical* aforementioned logic differ:

You'll, have noticed that in my previous explanation I say *"typically"* alot. I say that because npm has a [dist-tag](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-dist-tag) feature that allows the publisher of a package to modify the distribution tags. A short excerpt from the documentation for *dist-tag* reads as follows:

> By default, the `latest` tag is used by npm to identify the current version of a package, and `npm install <pkg>` (without any `@<version>` or `@<tag>` specifier) installs the `latest` tag. Typically, projects only use the `latest` tag for stable release versions, and use other tags for unstable versions such as prereleases.

So, if we consider again the `typescript` example described in the previous section. If the publisher associated the `latest` tag in the npm registry with version `4.2.0-dev.20201204`. For example if they run the following command:

```
npm dist-tag add typescript@4.2.0-dev.20201204 latest
```

then version `4.0.2` *will not* be installed (given a semver range of `^4.0.0`), and instead version `4.2.0-dev.20201204` will be installed.

Similarly, given the examples provided in your question, if we were to associate the `latest` tag with version `1.1.0-prerelease` (using the `npm dist-tag ...` command), and given a range specified as `^1.0.0` in the `dependencies` section of your *package.json*, then version `1.1.0-prerelease` will be installed and not `1.0.2`.

**Note:** I would consider these scenarios described in this section as quite rare, (they're certainly not typical but useful to understand), because as stated in that previous excerpt from the docs:

> Typically, projects only use the `latest` tag for stable release versions

---

**Additional info:**

Utilize the [npm view](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-view) command to discover information about a package(s) dist tags, particularly the `latest` tag. For example:

- The following command prints all tag information for the `typescript` package:

  ```
  npm view typescript dist-tags
  ```
- The following command prints the version associated with the `latest` tag for the `typescript` package:

  ```
  npm view typescript dist-tags.latest
  ```

For further info about distribution tags refer to [adding dist-tags to packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/adding-dist-tags-to-packages).